# Error on separating the router file in express js 4

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am new to **Node** and **Express**, i like to ***separate the route function in a separate files***, but i get error all the time.

my **app.js** file -

```
var express = require('express');

var index = require('./Routes/index');

var app = express();

app.use(index);

app.listen(2000);

console.log("Server working at port 2000");
```

My **Routes/index.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.use(function(req,res,next){
  console.log("url "+req.url);
});

router.get('/',function(req,res){
  res.send("Hi is it working?");
});

module.export = router;
```

When i run it, says error such as

```
app.use() requires middleware functions
```

If i put

```
`app.use('/',index);`
```

instead of 
`app.use(index);` 
then i got error like this

```
Router.use() requires middleware function but got a Object
```

Comment: `module.export = router;` is this a typo? It should say `module.exports = router;`.

Comment: @Jonas yes it solves the errors, even now i was not able to load the results for this url localhost:2000

Comment: @CharlesRajendran that's because of your current middleware, in `router.use()...` you should call `next();` after the `console.log` otherwise the router won't get to the next function which handles the response

Comment: @javiercf yes exactly thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So as a summary (and a correct answer) you had two issues:

**Typo:**

`module.export = router;` should be `module.exports = router;`.

**Middleware:**

Your middleware should call `next()` to pass the request to the next function. For more details take a look at [the documentation](http://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html).

Answer (score 1):

The issue is as mentioned in the comments:

```
module.exports = router;
```

instead of:

```
module.export = router;
```

Comment: This is wrong. `path` is optional and defaults to `'/'` if none is specified.

Answer (score 0):

I did two mistakes in the question

1. i had a typo. in the line `module.exports` where i put `module.export`
   ([jonas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5112436/jonas))
2. the next mistake is i need to put `next();` in `router.use()` middleware function. because i didn't put `next();` it don't know what to execute after the middleware function. i mean it don't know about my routes. ([javiercf](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2713441/javiercf))